# How to call controller's method in module (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

How to get some specific controller's `$scope` variable?

```
    myApp.factory('Comment', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var comment = {};

        comment.add = function (shortName, taskNum, message) {
            // how to call controller's method
            // the following line dosen't work
            myApp.ListPanelController.showTaskDetail(shortName, taskNum);

        }

        return comment;
    }



    myApp.controller('ListPanelController', ['$scope', 'Comment',
        function ($scope, Comment) {
            $scope.showTaskDetail = function (shortName, taskNum) {
                Tasks.get(shortName, taskNum).success(function (data) {
                    // do something
                });
            }
        }]
    );
```

Comment: You need to explain your scenario. Services are shared code\functionality and controllers are view specific. There should be no reason to call into a controller functionality from service.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't inject $scope into services, there is nothing like a singleton $scope.

But you can pass variables to your service or use `$rootScope` if you interesting to use `$apply`.

```
 myApp.factory('Comment', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($rootScope,$http){/*..*/}
```

But I would return `promise` and call `showTaskDetail` into controller.

```
myApp.factory('Comment', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($rootScope,$http){/*..*/}
```

Comment: I'v just got an answer. You're right. I have to pass $scope variable to my service. Thanks!

Comment: you can pass `$rootScope`